# How to redirect solr HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: http, https, solr, solr4

1.http://localhost:8983
2.https://localhost:8983
3.We currently employ a three-tier architecture consisting of a main server, a database server, and a Solr server. Access to the Solr server from the main server is currently done via HTTP. However, due to security concerns, we are planning to enable SSL. Despite attempting several solutions found on Google, we have been unable to make it work. Please note that our Solr version is 8.11.1, and on that instance, we have only installed Solr.

Comment: Please clarify, you've configured HTTPS (installed the certificate and it works over HTTPS) but you need to automatically redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS (protocol upgrade) or you have difficulties with the initial HTTPS setup?

Comment: Setup are done, I'm stuck in the request redirect